# add new function to object

Tags: javascript

If I have :

```
  function myFunc(a)
  {
    if(! (this instanceof myFunc) ) return new myFunc(a);
    this.myVar = "FOOBAR";
  }
```

How to make this to work? :

```
  myFunc(function() { alert(this.myVar )}); // output must be "FOOBAR";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `a` with `this`.

```
  function myFunc(a)
  {
    if(! (this instanceof myFunc) ) return new myFunc(a);
    this.var = "FOOBAR";

    a.call(this); // <-- Added this line
  }

  myFunc(function() { alert(this.var)}); // output must be "FOOBAR";
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/uferif/

Comment: Thanks, again something new :), btw is it possible to list object's methods?

Comment: oh.. it was : for(var //method// in //object//) :D. Thanks again for the answer

Comment: @John - Note this way to loop throw every item in an Object. Strings, Numbers, Functions, etc...